# android.permission.BATTERY_STATS api

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

I want more information about android.permission.BATTERY_STATS . what possibilities grants the permission android.permission.BATTERY_STATS. I know how to use it if I can read the android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED intent for the battery levels without declare such permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code that will get you the amount of battery used, the battery voltage, and its temperature.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        int scale = -1;
        int level = -1;
        int voltage = -1;
        int temp = -1;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
            Log.e("BatteryManager", "level is "+level+"/"+scale+", temp is "+temp+", voltage is "+voltage);
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
}
```

Comment: Note that you do not need the `BATTERY_STATS` permission touse this code.

Comment: yes i know but i just posted example i tried to explore this api